# list items spacing issue in IE7

Tags: html, css

In my web page, there are some items listed like this,

- Item 1
- Item 2
- item 3

I am wondering, it is taking much space in IE7(I haven't checked it yet on other versions of IE browsers) whereas in FF and Chrome it is fine. I have given "list-style-type: none" in my CSS. Still cant guess why it is taking space. Please help.

Comment: Used css reset ......... and ul, ul li{list-style:none;}

Comment: IE7 deprecation soon please...

Comment: `list-style-type: none` does not remove the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link [**Normalize CSS**](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) in your HTML page and your page should render the same in all major browsers.

Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

**Edit:**

There can be an issue with the margin and padding, keep it to 0-

```
ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
li { display:inline; }
```